# Showing that $5$ points lie on the same circle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

> We have an $\angle POQ=120^\circ$ and a point $M$ that is inside the
>   angle. Perpendiculars are drawn from $M$ to the arms and the angle
>   bisector of $\angle POQ$. Show that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral. 
>   [image]

From $AOBM \Rightarrow \angle AMB=60^\circ$ and from $OBMC \Rightarrow \angle BMC=120^\circ$, thus $\angle AMB=\angle AMC=60^\circ$. We notice $OBMC$ is inscribed. Let the center of the circumscribed circle $K(K; R)$ is $K$. Now, I am trying to show that $A$ lies on $K\Leftrightarrow AK=KB=R$. I don't see how to make it! Take you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $A, B, C$ lie on a circle with diameter $OM$.

**Hint:** $\angle ABC = \angle AOC$.

Can you complete it from here?

---

With regards to your observation that "We notice $OBMC$
 is inscribed", another way to continue from there is to show similarly that $OACM$ is a cyclic quad. Since the circumcircle of $OCM$ is uniquely determined, and must be the cyclic quad in both cases, hence $OACMB$ is concyclic.

Comment: Thank you! How can I show that $OACM$ is a cyclic quad?

Comment: How did you show that $OBMC$ is a cyclic quad? It's the same approach, hence "show similarly". (There is essentially no distinction between $A$ and $B$, since we can just flip $P$ and $Q$.)

Comment: $\angle BOC + \angle BMC = 180^\circ \Rightarrow$ OBMC is cyclic.

Comment: Great, in this case, because $A$ is on the other side of $OC$ than $B$, hence the "similar approach" is to show that $\angle AOC = \angle AMC $ (which is already stated in your image).

Comment: They are equal because $\angle AOC = \dfrac{1}{2} \angle POQ=60^\circ=\angle AMC$. But I don't see how we can say $OACM$ is cyclic from here. We need to show that two opposite angles add to $180^\circ$.

Comment: A slight diversion first: Given points $X, Y$, what is the locus of points $M$ that 1) Lie on the same side of line $XY$, and 2) $\angle XMY = \theta$?

Comment: They lie on the same circle?

Comment: If I got it, $\angle AOC=\angle AMC$, thus $AOMC$ is cyclic?

Comment: Yup! That's it.

Comment: I have just noticed it's easier to show that $AOBM$ is cyclic: $\angle AOB + \angle AMB = 180^\circ$. $OBMC$ is also cyclic; hence $OACMB$ is concyclic.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to show that these points are concyclic. IMO the way I listed is the best, since it follows immediately from the definition of "perpendiculars drawn from M".